# Facebook SDK and AngularJS manual bootstrap

Tags: facebook, angularjs

I need the FB sdk to be loaded before Angular, so any calls to the SDK will work.
I tried to manually bootstrap Angular where we are supposed to in FB init code, but it won't work.

I have no error message, but seems the bootstrap doesn't happen:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'database', ..........])

    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        .......
    })

    .run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {


        //Facebook load
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
                appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                //status     : true,
                cookie     : true,
                xfbml      : true
            });
                angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("loadAngular"), ['myApp']); // Manual Bootstrap

        };


        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }]);
```

on the html I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="loadAngular">

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div ng-controller="logController">
.....
```

If you have a clue why the bootstrap doesn't happen, please tell.

Comment: you can't bootstrap the app inside run function, it's the other way - bootstrap triggers run function, so you have to move the FB loading script completely out of `angular.module` part

Comment: This should be helpful: http://www.boynux.com/angularjs-facebook-integration/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [...]);
myApp.config(...);
myApp.run(...);

//Facebook load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
        appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        //status     : true,
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
    });
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Answer (score 1):

One directive is available for the same check the below url:

https://gist.github.com/ruiwen/4722499

or

https://github.com/Ciul/angular-facebook

**<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dDAmvdCibv46ULfgKCd3?p=preview)</kbd>**